# Pasting/Editing text into a text field through the chrome extension (content script)

Tags: jquery, events, google-chrome-extension, textarea, keyboard-shortcuts

I make a chrome extension that has content script part and popup part.
In the content script I check for focused textarea ( or it can be focused div with role="textbox" and contenteditable="true").

I add an div with an icon, so the icon will be in the right bottom corner. And I want to make such functionallity:

user clicks on the icon - content from text field is deleted and I paste new content there.

It seems to Grammarly and how it works.
But there is problem with pasting or Editing a text field. There are two main reasons:

1. `execCommand()` is deprecated and I would not like to use it, however it works well in case of a  text field.
2. there are different realializations of text field, for example here is how Instagram and Facebook make an analog of  tag:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1nsF.png)

or Outlook:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lv2V.png)

In case of default  everything is fine and I can edit it through my code using `execCommand()` method, it also works fine with outlook, I just do this:

```
// $textbox is an element founded by jquery

    $textbox.empty();
    $textbox.html(responseMessage);
```

but for instagram I tried the same, or even I pasted a child element with the same classes as were there and it didn`t work at all:

```
      const $allP = $textbox.find('p');
      $allP.remove();

// I append the same element that was in Instagram text field with my text
      $textbox.append(
        `<p class="xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r">
          <span data-lexical-text="true">
            ${responseMessage}
          </span>
        </p>`
      );
```

Also, I tried deleting existing children elements by this code:

```
   while (textbox.firstChild) {
     textbox.removeChild(textbox.firstChild);
   }

   textbox.appendChild(elementWithMyText)
```

Also, I tried making keyboard shortcuts events like ctr + a and ctr + x. And then dispatch this event to make working global shorcuts, but this didn`t work too.

Comment: execCommand is the most reliable method. The deprecation notice is premature because the alternative API is still being designed and it'll take probably 5-10 years before it's implemented. Note that you must focus the `contenteditable` element first when using execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: Thanks, but can I use this execCommand on other elements like <div>?
For me, this works only for <textarea>. I`m not sure, but as I remember I get "This not a function Error" when using it for div that has contenteditable="true.

Comment: Yes, see the example I've linked.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks a lot. I consider the option of deleting previous text and here is the problem why execCommand didn`t work. select is not a function for the div element.
`TypeError textbox.select is not a function`

So I found a workaround with the range and select API, but no matter what I tried, nothing worked with the Instagram textbox element. So now I can insert text, but I still can't delete the previous one.
`document.execCommand("delete", false, null);`
`const selection = window.getSelection(textbox);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
`

Comment: Use `document.execCommand('selectAll')`

Comment: My code:

textbox.focus();document.execCommand('selectAll')
document.execCommand('insertText', false, valueWithoutParagraphs)` 
It works only in case when I manually create a new paragraph in the textbox. I can`t understand this logic at all, how is it possible

Comment: Works for me in instagram's "new post" wizard.